# .xls to .csv on Mac

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I convert an xls file to a pipe delimited file?

Comment: In Windows you can change the "list seperator" in `Control Panel -> Regional Settings -> Advanced Settings` to `|` instead of `,` and then CSV will save with pipes.  Perhaps there is a OSX equivalent.  Alternatively use a text editor or sed/awk to find and replace.

Comment: @jase - are you OK with a Python solution ?

Answer (score 5):

If you're comfortable with Python first install the `xlrd` module, which is useful for reading Excel files.  You can get by doing:

```
% easy_install xlrd
```

in the Terminal.

Then give this rough script a try.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import xlrd
import csv

book = xlrd.open_workbook('an_excel_file.xls')

# Assuming the fist sheet is of interest 
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

# Many options here to control how quotes are handled, etc.
csvWriter = csv.writer(open('a_csv_file.csv', 'w'), delimiter='|') 

for i in range(sheet.nrows):
    csvWriter.writerow(sheet.row_values(i))
```

Run this script from the directory where the Excel file is located (`an_excel_file.xls` in the script) by invoking `python xls_to_csv.py` at the Terminal

There are a number of options for the `xlrd` objects, as well as the `csv` module, so check out the following if you need to tweak the settings:

- http://www.python-excel.org/
- [Python Excel Tutorial](http://python-excel.googlegroups.com/web/python-excel.pdf?gda=ZlCGf0IAAABlhHptG0URtFbXhfx0NsMgLI6eVmLExUXGtywvRr2QpNXEtWX7y7b6ByPnawQ3OxpV4u3aa4iAIyYQIqbG9naPgh6o8ccLBvP6Chud5KMzIQ)
- [CSV Module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html)

Comment: +1, people are afraid of command line solutions but it (always) becomes the best option....

Comment: Worked fine for me.  I wanted command-line to pipe into database (psql).  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

OpenOffice/NeoOffice lets you select delimiter on CSV saves.  Both are free and let you open .xls and .xlsx.

NeoOffice is the Mac port of OpenOffice, it is more Mac-like, but since it's a port of OpenOffice source it tends to trail in features just a bit.  I still recommend NeoOffice of the two though.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have Excel installed (which will do that automatically) you can use a Java library to do that easily. I would recommend you to take a look at [Apache's POI](http://poi.apache.org/).

Answer (score 0):

The most convenient solution for me was using [Shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-my/guide/shortcuts-mac/welcome/mac) and gnumeric.

1. Install [gnumeric using Brew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/gnumeric): `brew install gnumeric`
2. Import the Shortcut from this link: https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/830ce1b5f1eb4bf3a7453ec2fcef0b90

Or manually create it like this:

[image]

The good thing about this solution is that you'll have it available from the Services menu (when right clicking on a File) e.g:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Within Excel goto 'File > Save As' then under the 'Format' drop down select 'CSV Windows'. 
The key is the Windows version, why they have to include that just because it's a mac i'll never know...

Comment: @jimbo, thanks for your response. I dint find the way to comment. thats why i am asking you here. While saving as , there is no option to do it by 'pipe seperated'. It shows comma sepearated and space seperated but not pipe deleimited...

Comment: That still uses , as separator (+ messes around with quotes) The difference with plain CSV would be the line endings